# Flash messages handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

How do i print out flash messages in handlebars. Like i want to print out a helper message to the user if they enter a wrong login.

Routes:

```
router.post('/register-user', async (req, res, next) => {
    let newUser = req.body
    try {
        if (await userCheck.userCheck(newUser)) {
            const userExists = await User.exists({ username: req.body.username })
            if (userExists) {
                req.session.email = req.body.username;
                res.redirect('/apikey')
                console.log("User exists")
            } else {
                try {
                    req.session.email = req.body.username;
                    await userFacade.addUser(newUser)
                    console.log("New user")
                    res.redirect('/apikey')
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            }
        } else {
            req.flash("error", "Something went wrong during login, please try again.");
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

})
```

I have the flash message "error", but how do i show that on the page only if its set? Like if u were to use useStates in React.

I tried something like this:

```
    {{#if error}}
    {{error}}
    {{/if}}
```

App.js

```
//Express session 
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

//Flash
app.use(flash());

//Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to render the value you have saved to the flash store you would need to retrieve it from the store by calling `req.flash` using the same key that you used to save the value: `req.flash('error')`. You would then need to assign the returned value to a member of the data object you are passing to your `render` call in your GET handler for the `/` path - as this is the path you redirect your users to when you call `res.redirect('/')`.

Your GET handle for `/` may become something like the following:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { error: req.flash('error') });
});
```

Note: The result of calling `req.flash('error')` is an array. Your template will work because Handlebars stringifies array values, but `{{#each error}}{{this}}{{/each}}` would produce the same result when `error` is an array with a single element. If `error` were to have multiple elements, the `{{error}}` in your template would print all elements joined with commas, as in `error 1,error 2,error 3`.